# Raspbian + TP Link usb wifi problem

Tags: wifi

I have a TP-LINK TL-WN725N for my RPi, but I can't get it to work yet.

Trying to login from wpa_gui returns the error "**Failed to enable network in wpa_supplicant configuration**".

`lsusb` says `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.` but no model no or anything.

Then I do `lsmod` and I see my driver `8192cu 490361 0` so it's there but not used?

`iwconfig` returns "**no wireless extensions**" on both lo and eth0 (whatever that means).

This is where I'm stuck, what do I do next? It's my first time on linux.

*Also I have no ethernet cable available, so getting updates is difficult until the wifi works, can do it with USB from my laptop though.*

Comment: this is exactly the problem i have. Can someone tell me exactly how to set up this adapter step by step since i am very new to linux and raspberry pi, i received it 2 days ago and spent like 8 hours to resolve that. I need to know how to download on the pi , where the file supposed to be and what to do after that, and all this info is missing everywhere on the web, they assume you know already how to use the pi but i bet lots of noobs like myself are looking for the info. If i knew to use my pi i wouldnt search the web desperatly to make it work.

Comment: @user11816 It was complicated, but look up my other questions on this site related to this issue and the pieces will come together. Pretty much every question is a piece of the puzzle. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Used by* column of `lsmod` only lists other kernel modules that depend on this one, so a 0 doesn't necessarily mean that the module isn't used.

`iwconfig` reports `lo` and  `eth0` as having *no wireless extensions* because those are the *loopback* and *ethernet* interfaces. The more interesting part is that it doesn't list a device named `wlan0` (or similar), so apparently your WLAN adapter is not set up properly.

Since you were referring to the *TL-WN725N **v2*** in [another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/installing-drivers-from-usb-storage), you might need the *8188eu* kernel module instead of *8192cu*. Install it, as outlined there, and try `iwconfig` again. It should list a WLAN device then.