# Installing drivers from USB storage

Tags: driver

How do I copy a driver from a USB stick and what directory should I put it in?

I'm using Raspbian. The driver is found here and it's for my TP Link usb wifi dongle: http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=340048&uk=3912523090

I know the cp command but I don't even know how to find the USB device, so please try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: The file you linked to isn't available anymore. Where did you get the driver from?

Comment: http://www.mendrugox.net/2013/08/tp-link-tl-wn725n-v2-working-on-raspberry-raspbian/ that's where I found it, and I can confirm it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your USB stick should be auto-mounted in `/media`.
If it isn't, mount it using `mkdir /tmp/usb-stick && sudo mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/usb-stick`. You might have to replace `sda1` with the actual device name of your USB stick -- run `ls /dev/sd??` to find out which name it has been assigned.

As for where to put it, the [site](http://www.mendrugox.net/2013/08/tp-link-tl-wn725n-v2-working-on-raspberry-raspbian/) where you found the driver already tells you:

> Place the .ko object in the following path:
>   `/lib/modules/(your-kernel-version)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless`