# Raspbian, installing drivers with terminal

Tags: wifi, driver

I have a driver file `8188eu.ko` in `/home/pi`.

I'm wondering what command I write to install it? If I have to specify where to install it I need help there too. The driver is for a wifi dongle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
insmod /home/pi/8188eu.ko
```

However, beware that if that module was not built for your specific kernel, it will not load no matter what you do.

Comment: Thx this worked, and I got my wifi running. Until i rebooted, then it wasnt working anymore and iwconfig again showed nothing like before it was fixed. Any clues to what that could be?

Comment: Copy the file to `/lib/modules/3.6.11+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless`, run `depmod -a` and add `8188eu` to `/etc/modules` to automatically load the driver on startup. Most of this is also described on the [site where you found the driver](http://www.mendrugox.net/2013/08/tp-link-tl-wn725n-v2-working-on-raspberry-raspbian/) (according to [your other post](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/installing-drivers-from-usb-storage)).